# How to force GitHub Fork (origin) to take Repository (upstream) version

Tags: git, github

I have had a few issues with GitHub. I had made several commits one of the branches on my fork of upstream. We then created a new branch in which we didn't want the recent changes to be moved but GitHub copied those commits to the new branch as well. I want to reset my origin branch to be identical to the upstream branch with no new commits from me. I have tried several things and nothing seems to work the way I need it to. I tried to rebase my origin branch but now it wants me to merge all of the commits from other contributors from my origin to the upstream branch. All of those commits are already in upstream though. Is there a way for me to completely reset my origin branch without affecting upstream or anything in my other branches and then pull everything down from upstream and push it to my origin?

Answer (score 0):

```
git checkout new_branch
git reset --hard <SHA of last upstream commit>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to abort your rebase like so:

```
git rebase --abort
```

Then you can do one of the following two things:

```
git checkout upstream -t git://github.com/user/repo
git branch -D master 
# I am assuming master is where you made the commits you wish to lose
git branch -m upstream master
```

Or you can find the last common commit between master and upstream then do

```
git reset --hard commit_sha
git pull git://github.com/user/repo
```

If you then plan to update your GitHub master branch, you'll need to use

```
git push --force
```